# Putty XForwarding open file in same instance

Tags: linux, putty, xforwarding

I have to use Eclipse ( or some other gui editor ) over putty using XForwarding with xming to remotely edit some files.

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes I have an instance of eclipse open and in putty I try to open another file ( example: eclipse test.txt ), this tries opens another instance of eclipse.

Is there a way to have the file opened in the already existing instance?

Comment: Does this happen with Eclipse only? (Different editors use different methods of implementing single-instance behavior.)

Comment: It happens with other editors aswell.

Answer (score 0):

To enable such feature in eclipse, you need to start eclipse with this command:

```
eclipse --launcher.openFile <absolute path of file to open>
```

From what I read, this feature is not yet fully implemented, thus is disabled by default. More info: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me

Comment: Did you start first eclipse instance with this command? It won't work if you have previously started Eclipse in a usual way. You also need to open new files same way.

Comment: I tried every combination, no difference

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I highly doubt it eclipse related because simply running "eclipse filename" directly on linux works fine. So my guess is it has something to do with the forwarding